# What does the Steak N' Shake Time Machine commercial's "smart stuff" mean?

Tags: integration

I would like to know if there is any physical/mathematical significance to the following expression:

$$m\left(\left.\gamma v^{2}\right|_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}-c^{2}\int_{v_{0}}^{v_{1}}{\frac{2v/c^{2}}{2\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}}\:dv}\right)$$

[For reference, starting at 21 seconds](http://vimeo.com/45158196)

Does this equation have any real meaning and if so, what does it mean? I do notice an integral.

Answer (score 2):

It is junk, the units don't make sense. But the integrand is the velocity over c of a body accelerating towards lightspeed. The gamma is probably the Lorentz factor.

Comment: Well, of course the units don't match. They intentionally omitted some factors, or people would copy their time machine! :-)

Answer (score 0):

the integrand looks like the Lorentz factor from special relativity. lots of things cancel and the whole thing, in its entirety, just looks like junk to be honest.

From reading comments on other posts I think that people here might not view this question favourably, since you've not typed the maths up yourself (so people have to go looking) and many wouldn't expect stuff thrown in on a fast food advert to have any significant mathematical meaning.